# Assign User to a Company on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a User model:

```
    class User
      has_secure_password
      belongs_to :company, required: true
    end
```

And a Company model:

```
    class Company
      has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

I wand to create a form that assigns the User to a Company, either a new one if my app doesn't have a record with that company name, or a pre-existing Company.

This is what I have so far, but I am sure there is dryer method...

```
    class UsersController
      def create
        user = User.new(user_params)
        user.company = Company.find_by_name(params['company']) || Comapny.create(name: params['company'])
        if user.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          redirect_to singup_path
        end
      end
    end
```

Thanks!

Comment: A better place for this would be codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may consider `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in UsersController. Then you don't need to assign the company explicitly in the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create):

```
user.company = Company.where(name: params['company']).first_or_create
```

...which basically does what it says on the tin.